# Ангуляр добавляет по одному тэги стилей <style>

Tags: css, angularjs, style

Ангуляр  добавляет по одному тэги стилей,  как определить всё в один файл?
[image: clone <style>]

Использую такие модули: ngAnimate, ngAria, ngMessages, ngRoute, ngMaterial, textAngular, md.data.table

Comment: вообще клонировать не должен, должен только по одному добавлять. Какие модули используются?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые модули ангуляра при подключении проверяют какой режим работы выбран и в зависимости от режима добавляют `inline` стили, что позволяет не подключать отдельный css файлик для модуля.

Для настройки поведения в ангуляре есть [директива `ngCsp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp)

При использовании ее с параметром `no-inline-style`, например так

```
<html ng-app ng-csp="no-inline-style">
```

Теги `style` перестанут добавляться, но при этом необходимо будет подключить соответствующий css файл, который обычно находится там же где и сам модуль ангуляра.